# Wordpress with Nginx + php5-fpm gives me strange 502 errors and recv() ready() failed

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, php

I have recently encountered a new kind of problem with my Nginx php5-fpm installation. I use it for a production website with a lot of members and traffic. The website basically exists of a wordpress blog (as cms and for blogs), and a vBulletin 4 forum. The vBulletin 4 forum works perfectly with php5-fpm and Nginx, I added some Nginx rewrite rules (you know what I mean, for pretty urls under Nginx, not really mod_rewrite htaccess). The rest of the config is as default.

Installing wordpress (i did it after the forum) was not problematic either. But when running wordpress, I get strange 502 errors from Nginx when I'm working in the admin control panel, just clicking simple links. Also, some pages from the Wordpress admin seem to not completely load (as if the page is just the half of the page, the rest is white).

I hope you can help me understand (and fix) whats going wrong here.

Here is my error.log: http://pastie.org/private/praczievxolngnvg3wmreg And here my php5-fpm.log: http://pastie.org/private/jghgfun4yyjc8aoqpkkg

Thanks for all of your time and attention. If more info is needed, just ask and I will provide the corresponding files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and to be honest, it was a pretty stupid one:

I set the php5-fpm memory limit to 4096mb (i have 8gb ram dedicated) but I was thinking this was the total for all instances. But instead, each instance could be 4096mb which was why my requests got broken...